# Is there any other probability distribution model than gaussian for multivariate data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, matlab, probability, descriptive-statistics

Whenever we talk about the probability distribution of data having more than one feature, we have only one option i-e multivariate normal distribution. Is there any other probability distribution model exist for multivariate data? If yes, then how can we find its parameters using MLE in MATLAB

Comment: It's worth noting that the phrasing of this is incorrect (not to be an asshole). For linear regression models, we *assume* the data comes from a multivariate normal distribution, then we *estimate* the parameters of that distribution (i.e., the covariance matrix and mean vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a number of multivariate distributions, in theory. At the outset, we categorize them as `multivariate discrete distributions` and `multivariate continuous distributions`.

To start with, you may explore the following link for :
[multivariate discrete distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Multivariate_discrete_distributions) and the following for [multivariate continuous distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Multivariate_continuous_distributions).

There are entire volumes printed on the subject, for example, books by:  N. Balakrishnan, Norman L Johnson, and Samuel Kotz and these books are published by John Wiley and Sons, Inc.